# Is it possible to insert a value to a database from a select element and an input tag with the same id?

Tags: phpmyadmin

What I'm trying to do is insert value to my database using an id.
But my problem is i have a `<select>` and an `<input>` with the same id and it does not insert any data at all.
I need to insert the value from #subcat to `my_table`.
When #category selected value == "Tuition" i need to use only the `<select id="subcat">` and when #category selected value != "Tuition" i need only to use the `<input id="subcat">`
I've learned that id should be unique and sorry I am not that good in javascript yet.

Here is my code:

```
<form method="post" role="form">
    <label>Category</label>
    <select id="category">
        <option value="" hidden>Select Category</option>
        <option value="Tuition">Tuition</option>
        <option value="Miscellaneous">Miscellaneous</option>
        <option value="Others">Others</option>
    </select>
    <div id="for_blank">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Please select a category" readonly>
    </div>
    <div id="for_tuition" style="display: none;">
        <select id="subcat">
            <option value="" hidden>Select subcateogry</option>
            <option value="Full Payment">Full Payment</option>
            <option value="Downpayment">Downpayment</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="for_else" style="display: none;">
        <input type="text" id="subcat" placeholder="Enter Subcategory"
    </div>
    <script>
        $('#category').change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == "Tuition") {
                $('#for_tuition').show();
                $('#for_blank').hide();
                $('#for_else').hide();
            } else if ($(this).val() == "Miscellaneous") {
                $('#for_else).show();
                $('#for_tuition').hide();
                $('#for_blank').hide();
            } else if ($(this).val() == "Others") {
                $('#for_else).show();
                $('#for_tuition').hide();
                $('#for_blank').hide();
            } else {
                $('#for_blank').show();
                $('#for_tuition').hide();
                $('#for_else').hide();
            }
        });
    </script>
    <button type="submit" name="add_item">Add Record</button>
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['add_item'])) {
        $category = $_POST['category'];
        $subcat = $_POST['subcat'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO my_tbl (category, subcat)
            VALUES ($category, $subcat);";
    }
?>
```

Comment: They filtered my message badly here is the missing part, When #category selected value == "Tuition" i need to use only the select and when #category selected value != "Tuition" i need only to use the input

Comment: Two elements in a document with the same `id` is not valid.`id` must be unique in the document. If you rename one of them, you can add some logic on the PHP side to determine which one should be used.